# Views bulk operations interrupted due to insufficient rights

Tags: 7, rules, views, group

I created a view to replace the default view of the members page of the "Group" module.
When I am a site administrator the mass operation works.

When I am an authenticated user (No administrator of the site) and I select members to block them with mass operation, members are still active and the following error appears in the log (see screenshot).

When I disable my view and use the module's default view. Everything works fine.

[image]
[image]

Here is the export of my view :

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'group_members';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'group_membership';
$view->human_name = 'Membres';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Liste des membres';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'plus';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  3 => '3',
  9 => '9',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Appliquer';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Réinitialiser';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['exposed_sorts_label'] = 'Trier par';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Entête: Global : Texte non filtré */
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['id'] = 'area_text_custom';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['field'] = 'area_text_custom';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['empty'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['content'] = '<strong>Légende :</strong></br>
Actif = fait partie du groupe et a accès aux offres groupées.</br>
Bloqué = fait partie du groupe mais n\'a plus accès aux offres groupées.</br>
Invité = a été invité dans le groupe mais n\'a pas encore accepté l\'invitation.';
/* Pied de page: Global : Texte non filtré */
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['area_text_custom']['id'] = 'area_text_custom';
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['area_text_custom']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['area_text_custom']['field'] = 'area_text_custom';
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['area_text_custom']['empty'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['footer']['area_text_custom']['content'] = '<strong>Instructions :</strong></br>
<u>Pour démarrer une commande groupée :</u></br>
Étape 1 : mettre à jour la liste des membres.</br>
Étape 2 : aller sur la page du groupe et cliquer sur "Démarrer la vente".</br>
Étape 3 : compléter les dates et confirmer "Démarrer la vente".</br>
<u>Pour arrêter une commande groupée :</u></br>
Étape 1 : aller sur la page du groupe et cliquer sur "Arrêter la vente".</br>
Étape 2 : confirmer "Arrêter la vente".</br>
</br>
<i>Pour plus de détails, veuillez consulter la question suivante :</br>
lien</i>';
/* Comportement en l'absence de résultats: Global : Zone de texte */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['empty'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['content'] = 'Vous n\'avez aucun membre dans votre groupe.';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['format'] = 'plain_text';
/* Relation: Adhésion au groupe : Groupe gid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['id'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['field'] = 'group';
/* Relation: Adhésion au groupe : Utilisateur uid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['field'] = 'user';
/* Champ: Opérations en masse : Adhésion au groupe */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations_1']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations_1']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations_1']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations_1']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations_1']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations_1']['vbo_settings']['row_clickable'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations_1']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations_1']['vbo_settings']['entity_load_capacity'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations_1']['vbo_operations'] = array(
  'rules_component::rules_block_a_group_membership' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 1,
    'override_label' => 1,
    'label' => 'Bloquer les membres sélectionnés',
  ),
  'rules_component::rules_unblock_a_group_membership' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 1,
    'override_label' => 1,
    'label' => 'Débloquer les membres sélectionnés',
  ),
);
/* Champ: Groupe : ID du groupe */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['id'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['table'] = 'groups';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['field'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['relationship'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Champ: Utilisateur : Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Champ: Utilisateur : Nom */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'Nom d\'utilisateur';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['id'] = 'nothing_3';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['label'] = 'Nom d\'utilisateur';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['text'] = '[name]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]';
/* Champ: Utilisateur : Courriel */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['link_to_user'] = '0';
/* Champ: Adhésion au groupe : Statut de membre */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['label'] = 'Statut';
/* Champ: Adhésion au groupe : Group role */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['id'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['field'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['label'] = 'Rôles';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['separator'] = '';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['id'] = 'nothing_2';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['label'] = 'Metadata';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['text'] = 'metadata';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/metadata';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['id'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['label'] = 'Modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['text'] = 'modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/edit?destination=group/[gid]/member';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['id'] = 'nothing_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['label'] = 'Supprimer';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['text'] = 'supprimer';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/cancel?destination=group/[gid]/member';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['id'] = 'nothing_4';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['label'] = 'Actions';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['alter']['text'] = '[nothing_2]   [nothing]   [nothing_1]';
/* Filtre contextuel: Adhésion au groupe : Groupe gid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['group']['id'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['group']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['group']['field'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['group']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['group']['exception']['title'] = 'Tout';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['group']['default_argument_type'] = 'raw';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['group']['default_argument_options']['index'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['group']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['group']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['group']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Critère de filtrage: Adhésion au groupe : Statut de membre */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = array(
  'active' => 'active',
  'blocked' => 'blocked',
  'invited' => 'invited',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'status_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['label'] = 'Filtrer les membres';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = 'status_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['identifier'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  8 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  9 => 0,
  7 => 0,
  3 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['reduce'] = TRUE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'group/%/member';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Membres';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['weight'] = '0';
$translatables['group_members'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Liste des membres'),
  t('plus'),
  t('Appliquer'),
  t('Réinitialiser'),
  t('Trier par'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('<strong>Légende :</strong></br>
Actif = fait partie du groupe et a accès aux offres groupées.</br>
Bloqué = fait partie du groupe mais n\'a plus accès aux offres groupées.</br>
Invité = a été invité dans le groupe mais n\'a pas encore accepté l\'invitation.'),
  t('<strong>Instructions :</strong></br>
<u>Pour démarrer une commande groupée :</u></br>
Étape 1 : mettre à jour la liste des membres.</br>
Étape 2 : aller sur la page du groupe et cliquer sur "Démarrer la vente".</br>
Étape 3 : compléter les dates et confirmer "Démarrer la vente".</br>
<u>Pour arrêter une commande groupée :</u></br>
Étape 1 : aller sur la page du groupe et cliquer sur "Arrêter la vente".</br>
Étape 2 : confirmer "Arrêter la vente".</br>
</br>
<i>Pour plus de détails, veuillez consulter la question suivante :</br>
lien</i>'),
  t('Vous n\'avez aucun membre dans votre groupe.'),
  t('Groupe'),
  t('Utilisateur'),
  t('- Choisir une opération -'),
  t('Bloquer les membres sélectionnés'),
  t('Débloquer les membres sélectionnés'),
  t('ID du groupe'),
  t('.'),
  t(','),
  t('Uid'),
  t('Nom d\'utilisateur'),
  t('[name]'),
  t('Courriel'),
  t('Statut'),
  t('Rôles'),
  t('Metadata'),
  t('metadata'),
  t('Modifier'),
  t('modifier'),
  t('Supprimer'),
  t('supprimer'),
  t('Actions'),
  t('[nothing_2]   [nothing]   [nothing_1]'),
  t('Tout'),
  t('Filtrer les membres'),
  t('Page'),
);
```

Here is the Rules debug log :

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens This is the view we created in a previous question. Do you have a similar problem ?

Comment: Something else to check: VBO comes with a submodule [actions_permissions](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/views_bulk_operations/tree/actions_permissions.info) is it yes or no enabled? If it is, try to do a test with it disabled

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I will update my question with screenshot in English. The submodule is disabled and the rights of the view are "authenticated user". I still have the same problem.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I have updated the question. I have never used the Rules debug log. Is this what you asked for ?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I checked my view, my components and rights. Everything is correct, but impossible to block, unblock or delete a member with bulk operation. I do not understand where to get the blocking.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens 
I have disabled my extra rules and left the components blocked or unlocked. All goes well and the component message is displayed. The problem is that the member is not blocked and remains active. I only have the error of the screenshot in my journal.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Hello. Do you have any idea of the problem ? Thank you

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Thank you for all your answers. I just want to know if you have the same problem on your side. Because I do not know if this comes from my site or module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a similar scenario. Long story short:

- for my admin user (`user/1`) everything works as desired (as in your case).
- for an authenticated user which is not an admin, I also get a similar message in the log, which looks like so:

  > Skipped ***Block a group membership*** on group_membership Member Demo.User in Drupal for Sitebuilders ***due to insufficient permissions***.

Additionally, after I enable the Rules log for the admin user, I get a log that looks like so:

- Reacting on Event *Drupal is initializing*.
- Executing action rule: *Block a group membership*.
- Reacting on Event *Drupal is initializing*.

If however I perform the same scenario with the non-admin user, a similar Rules log does NOT include that "Executing action rule: *Block a group membership*.". That explains why your "members are still active" (as in your question), simply because the actual Rules Component related to that VBO action was not executed.

As a potential remedy, have a look at the VBO issue "[Custom Action Stopped Working](https://www.drupal.org/node/2527646)", which appears to be similar, and includes some possible work around (such as going back to a prior VBO release, if that's what you want to do ...). But this issue also appears to be related to "[Default action behaviors in getAccessMask()](https://www.drupal.org/node/2254871)". And that issue contains a patch attached to comment nr 29, which in subsequent comments seems to confirm that it does solve the issue (I've not QA-tested that patch ...).

I'm afraid that the above is "as good as it gets" for now ...

**Update**: even though I've not QA-tested it (yet), it seems that the patch mentioned in https://www.drupal.org/node/1334088#comment-11870650 is a fix for it (credits: [Mathieu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/54067/mathieu))

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I applied the patch but it does not work for me. I still have the same mistake in the paper.

Comment: Good evening and Happy New Year. Have you had time to study this question ?

Comment: @Mathieu Bonne Annee! Give me some time to refresh my memory about this question (I'll get back to you about it soon)!

Comment: This patch fixes the problem :-) https://www.drupal.org/node/1334088#comment-11870650

Comment: @Mathieu : interessant, merci! Check the update I added to my answer (to avoid that info gets lost if mods cleanup comments again).