# Drupal Commons, can't break-contact error

Tags: 7, users, debugging

I am using Drupal Commons (7.x-3.46).. Whenever trying to  "break contact" of a trusted-contacts, I get an error:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. Path: /batch?id=19&op=do StatusText: Service unavailable (with message) ResponseText: EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. Value at og_membership(): . in EntityDrupalWrapper->set() (line 756 of C:\Users\USER\Sites\commons-7.x-3.46or\profiles\commons\modules\contrib\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc).

An authenticated user can't break-contact at all. Trying as an administrator, it throws the error, but does complete the operation, and does breaks the contact.
This seems (to me) to be a crucial issue. If users can't remove a contact, I dare-not give them the possibility to add contacts in the first place..

At some point I thought it was all about VBO, so (I think) I uploaded the dev version of it, but I'm still getting the same behavior.
Also, changing the php version as suggested somewhere, made no difference.

In my search for a solution I've come across many similar issues, some of which I've listed below. But I haven't found the very same issue I'm facing, and with so many different solutions I'm not sure where to start. In some posts it's about views-bulk-operations. In others it's about the Entity module. Or about Organic Groups. Or indeed about the Trusted-Contacts module itself.
As I'm no patching-guru, I'm uncertain of how to proceed

Similar but not identical issues:

- [Views bulk operations interrupted due to insufficient rights](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221511/views-bulk-operations-interrupted-due-to-insufficient-rights)
- https://www.drupal.org/project/commons/issues/2588155
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1925412
- https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/issues/1871702

Comment: I tried the patch from the Commons issue queue ( https://www.drupal.org/project/commons/issues/2588155 ). It stops the error throwing, but users still cannot break contact. Any advice appreciated. Surely I'm not the only one facing this problem!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to resolve this problem, two patches are needed:

1  patch for the trusted contacts module as discussed in comment #2 here: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/commons/issues/2588155

2... and a patch for the membership-delete-action
 .../profiles/commons/modules/contrib/og/includes/actions/membership_delete.action.inc
as discussed here
https://www.drupal.org/project/opigno_lms/issues/2953675

works for me...
d